# Serialize list of dictionaries into accepted DataTable Ajax object

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I have a web application in which I'm retrieving some data into bootstrap table, what i want to do now is to use `jQuery DataTable` instead of the current as it has too much useful features.

Currently I'm retrieving the data from the server side using OOP approach, where a class object represents a data row in a particular table, and this object includes a dictionary which stores column names and values.

What I'm doing now is that I'm retrieving these class objects and append each dictionary of each object in a `List<Item>` and then serialize this list using `JavaScriptSerializer` object, and this object returns the following `JSON` format:

```
[
   {
   "slno":"2",
    "status_message":"Lights still flashing", 
    "crm_services_id":"1", "subject_id":"Lights are flashing",
    "severity_id":"5", 
    "user_id":"husain.alhamali", 
    "status_id":"1"
    },
    {
    "slno":"3", 
    "status_message":"lights working fine",    
    "crm_services_id":"2", 
    "subject_id":"Lights are flashing", 
    "severity_id":"3", 
    "user_id":"husain.alhamali", 
    "status_id":"2"
    }
]
```

When i tried to use this object to fill my `DataTable AJAX` I've got an error says:

> Invalid JSON response

I saw some examples of a valid `JSON` response that is acceptable to a `DataTable` which is as follow:

```
{
"data": [
[
  "Tiger Nixon",
  "System Architect",
  "Edinburgh",
  "5421",
  "2011/04/25",
  "$320,800"
],
[
  "Garrett Winters",
  "Accountant",
  "Tokyo",
  "8422",
  "2011/07/25",
  "$170,750"
]
}
```

Now my question is is there any tool or plugin that could re-format my `JSON` string into an acceptable format like the one above?

Comment: You're getting the error because DataTables (DT) doesn't know where to put the data. DT can handle objects like that but one thing to be aware of is that your objects keys aren't uniform so you need to be able to tell the DataTable how to react to keys that don't exist. Bear with and I'll work up a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this HTML:

```
<table id="example"></table>
```

This JS will create a table:

```
var data = [{
  "slno": "2",
  "status_message": "Lights still flashing",
  "crm_services_id": "1",
  "subject_id": "Lights are flashing",
  "severity_id": "5",
  "user_id": "husain.alhamali",
  "status_id": "1"
}, {
  "slno": "3",
  "status_message": "lights working fine",
  "crm_services_id": "2",
  "subject_id": "Lights are flashing",
  "severity_id": "3",
  "user_id": "husain.alhamali",
  "status_id": "2"
}];

function getColumns(){
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    let columnsArray = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(data[i]);
    for(k in Object.keys(data[i])){
      if(data[i].hasOwnProperty(keys[k])){
        columnsArray.push({
            "data":keys[k]
        });
      }
    }
    return columnsArray;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": getColumns(),
    "data": data
  });
});
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/srgavyem/). Hope that helps.

Comment: this is great actually, the jsfiddle example works perfectly, I tried to use it in my project but I'm getting some errors, I will try to overcome it but i can consider this as the answer for my question

Answer (score 2):

dataTable require json data in return from ajax response having following keys
1. data
2. draw
3. recordsTotal
4. recordsFiltered

Comment: Let me know if you are missing anything from this

Comment: ok dear I'm getting this idea but my question is how to do that dynamically in the C# side

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var data = list.Select(u => u.GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(p => p.GetValue(u, null)));
```

**example**

```
public class User
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Programm
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<User>();

        list.Add(new User
        {
            userId = 1,
            name = "name 1",
        });

        list.Add(new User
        {
            userId = 2,
            name = "name 2",
        });

        var data = list.Select(u => u.GetType()
                        .GetProperties()
                        .Select(p => p.GetValue(u, null)));
        Console.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            data = data
        }));
    }
}
```

**result**

```
{
    "data" : [
        ["1", "name 1"],
        ["2", "name 2"]
    ]
}
```